# Nativescript Unable to save ImageSource to file

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to save an ImageSource to a file.
I've followed the instructions in the docs under the [image-source](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source) section.
Here is what I've done:

```
let imageSource = new ImageSource();
var fileName = "Test.png";

var knownPath = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var folderPath = fs.path.join(knownPath.path, "Pictures");

var folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(folderPath);
var picturePath = fs.path.join(folderPath, fileName);

let saved  = imageSource.saveToFile(picturePath,"png");
```

The problem is that `saved` is always false, yet I cannot see why it is not being saved because it appears that `saveToFile` does not throw Errors.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you should give ImageSource some data with ImageSource.fromResource or fromUrl or ... .

Comment: You're right....I was initializing the  ImageSource in a promise and trying to save it outside the promise. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HabibKazemi pointed out in the comments, imageSource needs to have some source. In this specific case I was trying to savetofile outside the promise that populated the imageSources source.